# Restarting identity columns in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, identity, sequence

For `serial` columns used in Postgresql < 10, we manage the sequence by its name. We were able to reset a sequence with:

```sql
SELECT setval('table_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table));
```

From version 10, using identity columns, there is no need to use the sequence name. That's nice.

```sql
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN id RESTART WITH 1000;
```

How do I set the identity column to be the `max(id)` without knowing the sequence name?

As far as I can see from the [ALTER TABLE syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) there is no way to have a subquery to compute the start of the sequence.

I would like to write something like:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN id RESTART WITH (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do the same with identity columns - they also use a sequence.

You can use `pg_get_serial_sequence()` to get the name of the sequence:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('the_table', 'id'), coalesce(MAX(id), 1))
from the_table;
```

The above works for `serial` and `identity` columns the same way.

Comment: In case others have my same issue maybe there's an answer for them:
This didn't work for me, because I always get that the sequence does not exist.
When I SELECT * FROM information_schema.sequences , sure enough, there are no sequences anywhere to be found (even though I have a primary key as an identity column), so I try manually creating the sequence and assigning it to the table, and I get an error that it's an IDENTITY column (so I can't assign a manually created sequence I'm assuming?) So, I just gave up and went with a code based solution to do this instead of doing it directly in SQL.